# I keep hitting a road block when importing an iso into virtual box

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

The ISO came prepackaged from an instructor so, all I had to do was download the source, double click the file and import into virtual box. I also had to make a network adjustment (NAT) but, that's it.
I have been having some problems with V-Box running slow using this same Virtual Machine. This process has been successful previously (Installation wise. I deleted and re-installed this same Virtual Machine twice to fix some issues). Any help in helping me understand why this error is now occurring would be greatly appreciated. Thank You.

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Kali 2020 x64 Customized by zSecurity v1.2.

VMMR0_DO_NEM_INIT_VM failed: VERR_NEM_MISSING_KERNEL_API_2 (VERR_NEM_MISSING_KERNEL_API_2).

VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX).

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

Comment: This question is suitable for unix and stack exchange websites, since it not related anywhere o programming instead a general computing issue, for your helo enable vt-x virtualization from bios it will help you.

Comment: I tried that but, i have no keyboard or mouse control in bios/uefi panel